# Creating a foreign server in Postgres only if not exists

Tags: postgresql

As far as I know in order to create a foreign server (for a FDW) you need to do the following:

```
CREATE SERVER my_wrapper FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (
    dbname 'wrapperDB',
    host '127.0.0.1',
    port '5432'
);")
```

But because I create a migration script for an existing database, I want to be able to check whether this server exists with the same name and then create in a similar approach that is used upon tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable ...
```

Or in stored procedures:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.myfunction(text)....
```

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `DO` statement:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   CREATE SERVER ...;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN duplicate_object THEN
      NULL;  -- ignore
END;$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a foreign server exists with name 'my_server_name' using the following:

```
DECLARE
    srvExists       boolean DEFAULT false;
BEGIN    
SELECT true INTO srvExists FROM pg_catalog.pg_foreign_server 
   WHERE lower(srvname) = lower( 'my_server_name' );

IF srvExists THEN
   RAISE NOTICE 'foreign server my_server_name exists';
ELSE
   CREATE SERVER my_server_name FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
      OPTIONS (dbname '<your DB>', host '<your host>', port '<your port');
END IF;

END;
```